# TDD iOS - testNonConformingObjectCannotBeDelegate

Tags: ios, tdd

Working my way through the Test-driven iOS Development book and found this test which I'm trying to get my head around:

```
#import "QuestionCreationTests.h" 
#import "StackOverflowManager.h"

@implementation QuestionCreationTests {
@private
    StackOverflowManager *mgr; 
}

- (void)setUp {
    mgr = [[StackOverflowManager alloc] init];
}

- (void)testNonConformingObjectCannotBeDelegate {
    STAssertThrows(mgr.delegate =
    (id <StackOverflowManagerDelegate>)[NSNull null], 
    @"NSNull should not be used as the delegate as doesn't" 
    @" conform to the delegate protocol");
}
```

This tests that a non-conforming object cannot be a delegate. My understanding is that it uses `NSNull` as a sample non-conforming object. It then casts this to an object of type `id` that conforms to the `StackOverflowManagerDelegate` protocol. It then checks if this is equal to `mgr.delegate`. Then if this raises an exception it fails the test. My question is: how does this raise an exception?

Can someone clarify?

If it helps, here's the preamble:

> The application will ask the StackOverflowManager to provide its
>   delegate with questions on a particular topic.That means that the
>   StackOverflowManager class must have a delegate.

Fwiw, I'm aware that we'd now use XCTAssertThrows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`STAssertThrows` throws an exception if the expression does not throw an exception.

The setDelegate method of StackOverflowManager is -

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id<StackOverflowManagerDelegate>)newDelegate {
    if (newDelegate && ![newDelegate conformsToProtocol: @protocol(StackOverflowManagerDelegate)]) {
        [[NSException exceptionWithName: NSInvalidArgumentException reason: @"Delegate object does not conform to the delegate protocol" userInfo: nil] raise];
    }
    delegate = newDelegate;
}
```

As NSNull does not conform to the `StackOverflowManagerDelegate` protocol, the setter will throw an exception.  `STAssertThrows` will trap that exception and the test passes.  If the setter did not throw an exception, then `STAssertThrows` will throw an exception and the test will fail

Comment: Excellent explanation. One point though - what's this for: `(id <StackOverflowManagerDelegate>)` in the test?

Comment: That typecasts the NSNull object to an id type with StackOverflowManagerDelegate protocol to avoid a compiler warning. The cast isn't really valid because NSNull doesn't support the protocol, but the compiler 'trusts' you. This would result in a runtime exception if you did it in your program